# awk - <tr><td> output

Tags: html, awk

I have the following html

```
<table id="statTableHTML" class="table hidden"><thead><tr><th>Characteristic</th><th>GCI Score</th><th>Legal</th><th>Technical</th><th>Organizational</th><th>Capacity Building</th><th>Cooperation</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>United Kingdom</td><td>0.93</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.15</td></tr><tr><td>United States</td><td>0.93</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.18</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.15</td></tr><tr><td>France</td><td>0.92</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.14</td></tr><tr><td>Lithuania</td><td>0.91</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.17</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.16</td></tr><tr><td>Estonia</td><td>0.91</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.17</td><td>0.15</td></tr><tr><td>Singapore</td><td>0.9</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.13</td></tr><tr><td>Spain</td><td>0.9</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.18</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.17</td><td>0.15</td></tr><tr><td>Malaysia</td><td>0.89</td><td>0.18</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.12</td></tr><tr><td>Norway</td><td>0.89</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.18</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.14</td></tr><tr><td>Canada</td><td>0.89</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.19</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.17</td><td>0.14</td></tr><tr><td>Australia</td><td>0.89</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.17</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.18</td><td>0.14</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I would like to get all the values within the tr, td elements.

I have the following
`awk -F '</*td>|</*tr>' '{print $5, $7, $9, $11, $13, $15, $17}'`

however it only outputs the first row
`United Kingdom 0.93 0.2 0.19 0.2 0.19 0.15`

how can i write this so I get all the values of the rows?

thanks

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
awk -F '</*td>|</*tr>' '{ for (i=5;i<=NF-1;i+=2) print $i }' file
```

should get you the values, but they will be output in a single column so you will need to format the column further with e.g.

```
awk -F '</*td>|</*tr>' '{ for (i=5;i<=NF-1;i+=2) print $i }' test | awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/, "\t")}1'
United Kingdom  0.93    0.2 0.19    0.2 0.19    0.15
United States   0.93    0.2 0.18    0.2 0.19    0.15
France  0.92    0.2 0.19    0.2 0.19    0.14
Lithuania   0.91    0.2 0.17    0.2 0.19    0.16
Estonia 0.91    0.2 0.2 0.19    0.17    0.15
Singapore   0.9 0.2 0.19    0.19    0.2 0.13
Spain   0.9 0.2 0.18    0.2 0.17    0.15
Malaysia    0.89    0.18    0.2 0.2 0.2 0.12
Norway  0.89    0.19    0.2 0.18    0.19    0.14
Canada  0.89    0.2 0.19    0.2 0.17    0.14
Australia   0.89    0.2 0.17    0.2 0.18    0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='<tr><td>|</td></tr>' -F'(</?td>)+' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}' file
United Kingdom  0.93    0.2     0.19    0.2     0.19    0.15
United States   0.93    0.2     0.18    0.2     0.19    0.15
France  0.92    0.2     0.19    0.2     0.19    0.14
Lithuania       0.91    0.2     0.17    0.2     0.19    0.16
Estonia 0.91    0.2     0.2     0.19    0.17    0.15
Singapore       0.9     0.2     0.19    0.19    0.2     0.13
Spain   0.9     0.2     0.18    0.2     0.17    0.15
Malaysia        0.89    0.18    0.2     0.2     0.2     0.12
Norway  0.89    0.19    0.2     0.18    0.19    0.14
Canada  0.89    0.2     0.19    0.2     0.17    0.14
Australia       0.89    0.2     0.17    0.2     0.18    0.14
```

or if you prefer tabular instead of tab-separated output just pipe it to column:

```
$ awk -v RS='<tr><td>|</td></tr>' -F'(</?td>)+' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}' file | column -s$'\t' -t
United Kingdom  0.93  0.2   0.19  0.2   0.19  0.15
United States   0.93  0.2   0.18  0.2   0.19  0.15
France          0.92  0.2   0.19  0.2   0.19  0.14
Lithuania       0.91  0.2   0.17  0.2   0.19  0.16
Estonia         0.91  0.2   0.2   0.19  0.17  0.15
Singapore       0.9   0.2   0.19  0.19  0.2   0.13
Spain           0.9   0.2   0.18  0.2   0.17  0.15
Malaysia        0.89  0.18  0.2   0.2   0.2   0.12
Norway          0.89  0.19  0.2   0.18  0.19  0.14
Canada          0.89  0.2   0.19  0.2   0.17  0.14
Australia       0.89  0.2   0.17  0.2   0.18  0.14
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check how your regex is matching each field.](https://tio.run/##pZTfT8IwEMff@SuayQMa4hyogwSWKMEfEfABfDI@nGtlF2e7tCVmIn87dgxxBBcafeiP@7a9T@96Kby/LpeX/evb0fxq3HU67pGmwWc2yMBZVA7miUSuSfWsTqq@aW3TPC/rmlmXyZ6/qKgkRl2rntRBSkgP5y9C1pAgJ7lNci9Yz@1HfFoslx0NzzEjSLuO0qAnmXUzGQ4cEsagVNfJ1yOklHEn6OiIATWDzKZBLwIJoWYSlcaw4xopk697t2QcCsk2yoBNId5YExZGHMOCci@nwPEDNApekHuQQIg6JZczjCny6c@KEAmTq/255mZXcr@v9yxour4lDR44akbJnTlPxZvZRFfyyXG7WTAahbnXtlnwznJjhd5mjU0umbJCtf6KupLAQ1ZkNP4XzukuY4A6mpmXgSLGK/PmW2HOdzF9pYUlpNyvvydfY/P@kORVucFYeS7d1fyFkgByG0LLJou/xTGEGFK1la1W28ZzaRobu5CRkO@QliKsotpbXT3gQEvjsKtgfw/jYqa0hBjtML5VXEWMu/5r3NVHGVS@AA) Each line of the output starts with the number of the field you came up with. Empty lines mean `<tr>` and `<td>` were side by side.

You could try this, instead:

```
BEGIN{RS="<\/?t[dr]><\/?t[dr]>";ORS=" "}
$0 && !/^</
END{printf "\n"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZRtT8IwEMff8ylqY3jpeFCBOGZkIhJ5SBy@Ek2OtbLG2S1dCZmEzz73gDACC42@2t3/bve7uzaF5WcUdbq9/mj1bLWxPtVu5SsRb8bOwjfjJITwunReQeUyOtPeda3UHd2vfMG4/EB4yvE6inQJM5ciRto4kCAnifc4GQ4wsl0IgjbO4g4jhHJs6NKhQOKPSEzDdECALalggWS2rsVSIvfMPrJsT9CtMqBzcLfehNoOZ3ZOGYs5cPYNknk8J5vgg81kiDoL5hLG57uI5/lUpPmZpiUtab/tzTwSbrokxgtnkhL0FP9PvK84iaRy5aJVzzm1nF1tqQSqV5mTovdZVrxLGiihmn9FPQjgNs0zav8b5/KQMWDSWcQnA3lMtahaQwlzfYjpBtJThBTXbZzYlxWfP/jZrdxilCoXZtWPUHxgXIXQVNnisTmG4EIY7G2r2VKpXLjG2iFk5IklhIUIpalO3i4TOJDCOdRucOME424RSAEuU8M0lObKY7TNW6OlD6VR@gE)

It removes all `tr`s and `td`s, regarding them as record separators. The output record separator becomes a space. Then, only prints non-blank records that do not start with `<`, i.e., that do not start with a html tag. Also prints a trailing newline, for the sake of POSIX definition of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your attempt, seems like number of columns per row is known to be `7`. So, you can use tools like `xpath` or `xmllint` and then use `pr` to format the output.

```sh
$ # same as: xmllint --xpath '//tr/td/text()'
$ xpath -q -e '//tr/td/text()' ip.html | pr -7ats' '
United Kingdom 0.93 0.2 0.19 0.2 0.19 0.15
United States 0.93 0.2 0.18 0.2 0.19 0.15
France 0.92 0.2 0.19 0.2 0.19 0.14
Lithuania 0.91 0.2 0.17 0.2 0.19 0.16
Estonia 0.91 0.2 0.2 0.19 0.17 0.15
Singapore 0.9 0.2 0.19 0.19 0.2 0.13
Spain 0.9 0.2 0.18 0.2 0.17 0.15
Malaysia 0.89 0.18 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.12
Norway 0.89 0.19 0.2 0.18 0.19 0.14
Canada 0.89 0.2 0.19 0.2 0.17 0.14
Australia 0.89 0.2 0.17 0.2 0.18 0.14
```